# Get Azure AD user profile from Azure ObjectID

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

I want to fetch user profile information such as user image, email id , etc in Microsoft Teams. I'm having Azure ObjectID of the user and with that i need to get complete user profile from AAD.
I tried to get user profile with graph API by passing access token but its giving me Invalid token error.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to get the token as well as the API URL you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official API reference,

1. to get user profile, you can use [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API. And the required permission would be:

[image]

2. to get user image, you may use [Get photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) API. The required permission would be:

[image]

3. you can add permissions on Azure portal for your app registered

[image]